# Do algorithms implemented in analog circuits suffer from numerical instability?

Tags: signal-processing, numerical-methods

Numerical instabilities occur when floating-point numbers of very different magnitude are added together, or when we attempt to factorize matrices with large condition numbers, and so on. This occurs due to a finite number of bits allocated to manipulate floats.

Would the same algorithms implemented in analog circuits (electrically-based or otherwise) perform any better? Intuitively it doesn't seem so, because it seems like representing large numbers with small fractional parts is sensitive to noise too. Is there any physical theory to justify this?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article on analog computers: "Analog computers do not suffer from the quantization noise inherent in digital computers, but are limited instead by analog noise." The whole article is rather well-written: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct.  If you implement the same algorithms in analog, they will be sensitive to noise in the same way that the digital implementations are sensitive to quantization errors.  In addition, the analog versions will have all kinds of non-linearity errors and distortions that aren't present in the digital version.

As for a "physical theory that justifies this", there are lots of concepts in information theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory), like entropy and channel capacity, that relate noise levels to the amount of information a signal can represent.